# MAGMI - Does it import attribute sets & attributes?

Tags: magmi

Does MAGMI come with an Attribute Set importer? Does it come with an Attribute Importer? I am confused with the MAGMI docs. It does not look like MAGMI handles attributes and attribute sets.

Answer (score 1):

Magmi can import an attribute set value or attribute values it does not create them.

You can easily (and relatively quickly) create these from the magento admin panel at **Catalog > Attributes**. See the [Magento User Guide](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/attributes.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog%7CAttributes%7C_____0) for more details

Answer (score 1):

It imports attributes, attribute sets with groups and the corresponding attribute-to-set associations from 3 different csv files to the magento database before the product update will start. It lets you choose for each entity type (attributes, sets, associations) if you want to update existing, create new, delete marked records and/or prune all records which were not given in your import data.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Attribute_set_importer